# how to match either word or sentence in this Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a decent familiarity with regex but this is tricky. I need to find instances like this from a SQL case statement:

when col_name = 'this can be a word or sentence'

I can match the above when it's just one word, but when it's more than one word it's not working.

```
s = """when col_name = 'a sentence of words'"""

x = re.search("when\s(\w+)\s*=\s*\'(\w+)", s)

if x:
    print(x.group(1)) # this returns "col_name"
    print(x.group(2)) # this returns "a"
```

I want group(2) to return "a sentence of words" but I'm just getting the first word. That part could either be one word or several. How to do it?

When I add in the second \', then I get no match:

```
x = re.search("when\s(\w+)\s*=\s*\'(\w+)\'", s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match all characters other than single quotation mark rather than matching letters, digits and connector punctuation ("word" chars) with the Group 2 pattern:

```
import re
s = """when col_name = 'a sentence of words'"""
x = re.search(r"when\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*'([^']+)", s)
if x:
    print(x.group(1)) # this returns "col_name"
    print(x.group(2)) # this returns "a sentence of words"
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/hIdDbI)

The `[^']` is a negated character class that matches any char but a single quotation mark, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EeUlKz/1).

In case the string can contain escaped single quotes, you may consider replacing `[^']` with

- If the escape char is `'`: `([^']*(?:''[^']*)*)`
- If the escape char is `\`:  `([^\\']*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)`.

Note the use of the raw string literal to define the regex pattern (all backslashes are treated as literal backslashes inside it).

Comment: Cool. Thank you!